# Tense not validating

Tags: tense, gerunds, present-simple

"He likes sleeping."

This is a simple present tense but my question is sleeping act as a object in it ?If not then why verb is with ing (I know it is gerund).

Because as far as I know sleep is a verb.

And simple present tense structure is like Sub + verb (s or es) +object.

Sorry,If I used bad english.(I am beginner).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered your own question!

> [gerund](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/gerund): a word ending in "-ing" that is made from a verb and used like a noun

So, here take the verb 'sleep'. Add *-ing'*, it becomes *'sleeping'* which is a gerund **used** like a noun.

> What does he like? ~ *sleeping* (noun)

Such gerunds are used when we are talking about the action as a habit/choice/hobby etc. If we use a normal tense verb, it *may* mean a single time event (as in he likes to sleep (when he's traveling by train)).

But if we say, `he likes sleeping`, we are mostly talking about his habit/preference.

Comment: You know what you are awesome :)
Thanks a lot Maulik :-)

Comment: I think `looking forward to + gerund` is quite the same case.